# Show that the extension $\mathbb{R}(X) \supseteq \mathbb{R}\left(X^2+\frac{1}{X^2}\right)$ is Galois and find its Galois group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to show that the extension $\mathbb{R}(X) \supseteq \mathbb{R}\left(X^2+\frac{1}{X^2}\right)$ is Galois, and then find its Galois group $G$ and all subgroups with the corresponding subfields.

Normally when we work with extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ we find an algebraic element $\alpha \in L \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ and an irrreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$. From there we can prove if the extension is actually a splitting field of a polynomial, find the degree of the extension and its Galois group.

How can I approach the problem in this case? Any tips on where I should start?

Comment: Another equivalent definition of being Galois: [$K/F$ is Galois iff $F$ is the fixed field of a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension#Characterization_of_Galois_extensions). Can you find the subgroup fixing $X^2 + 1/X^2$? I can see at least two automorphisms that do.

Comment: Let $\alpha=X^2+1/X^2$ then you can see that $X$ is a root of some polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb {R} (\alpha) $. This is also the minimal polynomial for $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at $\sigma: \mathbb{R}(X) \mapsto \mathbb{R}(X)$ given by $\sigma(X)=-X$, and $\tau:\mathbb{R}(X) \mapsto \mathbb{R}(X)$ given by $\tau(X)=1/X$.

Show that both $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are self-inverse automorphisms, and that they commute. Then $\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/{2}\times \mathbb{Z}/{2}.$
Then, $\mathbb{R}(X)^{\langle \sigma \rangle}=\mathbb{R}(X^2)$, while $\mathbb{R}(X)^{\langle \tau \rangle}=\mathbb{R}(X+\frac{1}{X}$).

It also follows that $\mathbb{R}(X)^{\langle \sigma,\tau \rangle} = \mathbb{R}(X^2+\frac{1}{X^2}).$ Therefore, the extension is Galois with Galois Group $\mathbb{Z}/{2}\times \mathbb{Z}/{2}.$